# Tipagem em Python

Tags: python, tipagem

É possível usar tipagem estática em Python? Por exemplo se eu declaro uma variável do tipo `int` e depois atribuo o valor 'um' não ocorre nenhum erro, queria saber se tem como impedir esse tipo de coisa.

```
x: int

x = 'um'
```

Comment: Amigo, você sabe que x:int é uma anotação né?

Comment: Sim mas eu quero saber se tem como usar para tipar uma variável.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+tipagem

Comment: É apenas uma anotação, o python não vai impedir de passar uma string ou uma lista no `x` por exemplo, porém a IDE vai emitir um warning dizendo que tem uma anotação dizendo que é `int` e vc está passando uma string. Doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @MatheusCezario A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Diretamente em Python padrão não tem jeito, só pode dar o [*hint*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) mesmo. Você pode fazer uma ferramenta de análise estática que verifique o código e informe erro quando tentar atribuir um valor inválido para uma variável anotada com determinado tipo. Talvez até tenha uma ferramenta pronta de alguém que faça isto, mas desconheço. Fora isto tem dialetos de Python com tipagem estática mesmo, por exemplo [Cython](https://cython.org/) ou [MyPy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/).